# can you adjust the kerning between individual letters with Cufon?

Tags: font-face, cufon, kerning, letter-spacing

Hey all.. 
exactly as it sounds.

currently using @fontface, lettering.js, and kern.js to get this word pretty and scalable.

would love to do all that and throw a pretty gradient on top.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - it works. The spans injected by lettering.js wrap the cufon elements, and any CSS created using kern.js will automatically apply.

I am using cufon as a fallback for browsers that don't support fontface, and it has worked fine with lettering.js.

Answer (score 0):

For cufon use eg. letterSpacing: "-1px"